# Cannot post multiple and long requst Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, request, http-status-code-504

I need to send post request to Another API, which will return result about 7 seconds.

If I try to send post one by one, it's working great. But as soon as I loop it or send multiple request, it returns errors.

The errors are sometimes `Error: socket hang up` or `status code: 504`

I've tried

- multiple `then().then().th`
- `async/await` inside for loop
- `aync/await` line by line like this

  ```
    const toonifyNewFileName = `./uploads/Toonified-toonify-${baseFileName}`
    const toonifyRes = await axios.post(toonifyUrl, formData, {headers: headers})
    var {data:{num_faces, b64_encoded_output}} = toonifyRes;
    var base64Buffer = Buffer.from(b64_encoded_output, "base64");
    writeFile(toonifyNewFileName, base64Buffer, err => console.log("DONE 1"));

    const comicNewFileName = `./uploads/Toonified-comic-${baseFileName}`
    const comicRes = await axios.post(comicUrl, formData, {headers: headers})
    var {data:{num_faces, b64_encoded_output: newB64}} = comicRes;
    var base64Buffer2 = Buffer.from(newB64, "base64");
    writeFile(comicNewFileName, base64Buffer2, err => console.log("DONE 2"));
  ```

It doesn't matter with `writeFile()`, I've deleted, it didn't work.

My guess is that since the first request takes about 7 to 8 seconds, that's why it causes error for next request?

---

**to sum up**

I need to post multiple requests that each of them takes about 7 to 8 seconds.
But it returns `socket hang up` error or `status code: 504 GATEWAY TIME OUT`

what should I do?

Comment: Did you try using `timeout` parameter? https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my problem was not about axios, it's about `form-data`.

the first request going well, but seconds, i don't know why but I think there are problem with `form-data`, maybe the form data is null something

so I figured out to initialize formdata every time I send `axios.post()`

here's the code

```
const arr = [some arrya i need, like 4 elements];

await Promise.all(arr.map(async(elem) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', createReadStream(pictureUri));
    const headers = { ... };
    ...
    const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {headers: headers});
    do some work...
}))
```

key is I had to generate `form-data` every time, even though it'll be always same...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the socket is hanging! Don't bother with http, it is a little complex. Use node unirest and it closes the data stream.
With this, you can loop and send files in batches remotely.

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var req = unirest('POST', 'localhost:3200/store/artifact/metamodel')
  .attach('file', '/home/arsene/DB.ecore')
  .field('description', 'We are trying to save the metamodel')
  .field('project', '6256d72a81c4b80ccfc1768b')
  .end(function (res) { 
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error); 
    console.log(res.raw_body);
  });
```

Hope this helps!